# How to represent a JSON object variable with Proto definition

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java, proto

I want to define a request message in gRPC which should have a Json Object as a field
For e.g.

```
message UserRequest{
    string name = 1;
    string city = 2;
    string email = 3;
    metainfo = 4;//A Json Object variable which can have any number of elements
}
```

How do I represent the metainfo property within proto definition?
I have tried using below definition but it didn't work.

```
message UserRequest{
    string name = 1;
    string city = 2;
    string email = 3;
    google.protobuf.Any metainfo = 4;
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you want a `.google.protobuf.Struct`, via [struct.proto](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/struct.proto) - this essentially encapsulates a `map<string, Value> fields`, and is broadly akin to what you would want to describe via JSON. Additionally, `Struct` has custom JSON handling, as mentioned in the file:

> The JSON representation for `Struct` is JSON object.

So:

```proto
    .google.protobuf.Struct metainfo = 4;
```